# Using Archemedian property prove that $1/n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis

Using Archemedian property prove that

$$\frac{1}{n}\to 0$$ as $$n\to \infty$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be any given number. We want to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over n} =0$

Now, by Archimedian Property, there exists $N\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $N\epsilon>1$.
In other words, $\epsilon>{1\over N}$.

For all $n\geq N$, ${1\over n}\leq {1\over N}<\epsilon$.

Thus, for all $n\geq N$,$$\Bigg| {1\over n} - 0\Bigg|<\epsilon$$

This proves that $\lim_{n\to\infty} {1\over n} =0$